# Android: when spinner item is selected how to prompt for additional details

Tags: java, android

Trying to make a checklist type app that when you select an element from a spinner you will be prompted for additional information. For instance if you select apple it will ask you how many and give you an editable text box to select.

Should I design the page so that it uses a new intent after each item is selected and creates a new page with the prompting and previous selections in it?

Or is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnItemSelectedListener` and `AlertDialog` is the way.

1.Use OnItemSelectedListener and override the `ItemSelected()`

2.create and show the `AlertDialog` with edittext inside the `ItemSelected` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not taking so many inputs from user then you can create a simple AlertDialog for getting those values on every item selected from Spinner or if there are lot of inputs needed then you should call a separate activity for that.